# Conflict between titlesec and colortbl

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I'm getting a conflict between `titlesec` and `colortbl` that I can't seem to fix.

The minimal working example is below. As soon as I put a `\section` in, pdflatex errors with `! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.9 \section{First Section}`

In order to make it work I have to either:

- Not use `sections` (obviously not feasible)
- Not use my section style (but the journal requires it!)
- Not use coloured tables (but I want to!)

Can you help me make this document with my section heading style included and coloured cells in the table?

Thanks,
Sven.

*Edited below to include the full set of `titlesec` and `titleformat` command I use*

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}


\begin{document}

\section{First Section}
\subsection{a sub Sec}
If I define a section (by uncommenting above)... it fails.
\subsubsection{Again}

If I then do one of:
\begin{itemize}
\item{Remove the table (and colortbl package}
\item{Remove my section formatting above}
\end{itemize}
... my doc will compile, but I won't have the style I want.

\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabular}{ |c|l|l } \hline
\rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{How can I get colored table cells and keep my section heading format?}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

For reference in case of package conflicts, here is the list of other packages I'm using in my complete document (but don't seem to affect this particular bug):

```
\usepackage[left=18mm,top=20mm,right=18mm,bottom=25mm,includehead,nofoot,headheight=0pt,headsep=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
```

Comment: Please call  package `hyperref` as last package ...

Comment: @sven It seems the problem lies with your use of `\MakeUppercase` in `\titleformat*`. I get no error if I remove it.

Comment: @Jubobs: Thanks for helping find that. Just out of curiosity, is it normal for this problem to only occur after I put in the `colortbl` package? Because my document would be created without error even with the `MakeUppercase` issue you identified, as long as it didn't have `colortbl` too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no conflict between the packages; the problem is that `\MakeUppercase` requires an argument; you can overcome this by using the extended syntax for `\titleformat` and the `explicit` option for `titlesec` to have explicit access to the title:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}

\section{First Section}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|l|l } \hline
\rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Problem solved!}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice also that I used `\MakeTextUppercase` from the `textcase` package (it's safer than the standard `\MakeUppercase` in titles).

After the edit to the original question, here's now the code with the necessary modifications for the other sectional units:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}{\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em}{0em}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ |c|l|l } \hline
\rowcolor{red} A    & B     & C     \\ \hline
Hello World         & other     & \cellcolor{blue}stuff\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Problem solved!}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo, that indeed fixes the MWE. Can I trouble you to help me "safe-ify" the following set of section adjustments:

    \usepackage{textcase}
    \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
    \titleformat{\section}
      {\normalfont\bfseries\filcenter}{\thesection}{1em}   {\MakeTextUppercase{#1}}
     \titleformat*{\subsection}{\bfseries}
     \titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}

Comment: Argh, sorry the comment didn't format how I intended. I'm no longer getting a problem with the MWE I posted, but there's something in my full document that still won't compile properly even after fixing the `titlesec`. I'll try and identify it enough to recreate in the MWE... sorry, might take a few minutes....

Comment: @sven mo problem; code in comments looses formatting (adding back-ticks helps a little).

Comment: Ok Gonzalo, I've edited my question to include all section formatting that I do... I left in the original stuff that was working without the `colortbl` (I understand that using the explicit option means they're bad... I just couldn't get it to work)

Comment: @sven please see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. For my own education: how does your code produce bold `subsubsections`, but there's no longer a `\bfseries` being applied to it?

Comment: @sven that is because in the `article` document class subsubsection titles are by default bold-faced and with `\normalsize`, so no change is required.